# Issue with persisting specific relation with Doctrine2 ODM

Tags: doctrine-orm, object-persistence

I am using **Doctrine 2 MongoDB ODM**, all working fine except 1 specific relation. What's obscure is that I have seemingly identical relations in the project and they all work just fine

```
namespace Project\Entities\World; // same NS as class, but this is after
// splitting functionality from Entity to MappedSuperclass, didn't work either

/**
 * @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Project\Entities\World")
 * @var IWorld
 */
protected $world;
```

used in Project\Entities\PlayerCharacter (**extends** Project\Entities\World\Object mentioned above)
=>

```
namespace Project\Entities;

/**
 * @Document(collection="worlds")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class World {
    /**
 * @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="PlayerCharacter")
 * @var ArrayCollection
 */
protected $playerCharacters;
}
```

When I set the $world variable, it's fine in the PHP script. Even $objectManager->refresh($character), $character->getWorld() === $world turns out fine. But it does never appear in the database itself (**die** right after setting it and flush to make sure it is never changed by accident somewhere) on the PlayerCharacter's end, only on the World side

On the other hand

```
class PlayerCharacter {
/**
 * @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="User")
 * @var User
 */
protected $user;
 }
```

=>

```
/**
 * @Document(collection="users")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User {
    /**
     * @ReferenceMany(targetDocument="PlayerCharacter")
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $characters;
}
```

works

In simplified version:
- PlayerCharacter::$user <==(1:N)==> User::$characters
(and all others) are fine, while only
- PlayerCharacter::$world <==(1:N)==> World::$playerCharacters
works only on the World side

Looking at it many days, can't find anything different.

- Tried renaming property names, no change
- Hydrator entry for character--->world looks identically to others
- When I add the entry semi-manually (via RockMongo), it works fine
- Creating the "world" field as NULL makes no difference, with {} it says "Undefined index: $id", but I guess that's an expected behaviour
- Entities separately work very fine too, it really just is this one relation

Is there anything I am missing/overlooked or what can I do to discover why is it not getting persisted

(will edit the post if there's need for more info)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the thing was there were many entries in the UoW some containing World => null and some World => ...WorldProxy, so the latter probably got overwritten

Using flush() before the assignment solved this